# Dynamic property naming in apache NIfi?

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

I am assigning a value to "reasonId" and later using it as a dynamic property in other processor(ExractText).
[image]

Now, I want to assign this as an dynamic property so that I can store some API response into this. Means reasonId value and Api response both should change evertytime.

[image]

Here I want this [${reasonId}=(.*)] to be like this:-

6099 = Api response     (Everytime value of 6099 should change as it is a dynamic variable)

But,

I am getting it like this

${reasonId}=Api response

Why there is no 6099 instead of reasonId. Does it means Dynamic property assignment is not working properly? or I can use some jolt spec and all for this?
Basically I want reasonId to hold its value 6099 and Api response should be store in 6099 instead of ${reasonId}.

Comment: Can you share your flow in a picture?

Comment: FlowFile has API response

Comment: @MohammadReza FlowFile has Api Response, See, API response is perfectly storing in ${reasonId} but I dont want it as ${reasonId}. I want this 6099 value to be replace with ${reasonId}, that's why I tried using dynamic property. ...........So that my reasonId value keeps changing in every call. I want to store this (.*) Api Response in 6099 and in next call when reasonId value will be lets assume 6100 API response should store in 6100.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can't achieve it like this.

There's no documentation that Nifi lets you dynamically set a flow file attribute key. You can use `$` just in the value.

Suppose you successfully add `6099 = Api response` in your flow file. Now, how you can use `6099` as a key to get your API response? I don't have any idea about that.

Please check it [this link](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Support-Questions/Dynamic-property-naming-in-NiFi/td-p/216692).

**ExecuteScript:**
You can create the properties you want with this processor like the exact thing you want.

**JoltTransformJSON:** But I think it's better to use the JOLT processor for this case. For example, you can create a flow file content like this:

```json
{
  "6099": // api response
}
```

**Update:** Real example with `JoltTransformJSON`

After you got your response use a `JoltTransformJSON` processor and put the following code as its value:

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "@": "${reasonId}"
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: No I dont want 6099 to be add in my flowfile

Comment: @Destiel Use `ExecuteScript`

Comment: How can I do so through jolt as you have mentioned, it seems to be a right approach, If I do so on 2nd call of API this 6099 will get replace by another reasonID?

Comment: @Destiel Or you can set again all flowfile content in a flowfile attribute with `ExtractText` processor

Comment: @Destiel Your second request is not related to the first one.

Comment: @Destiel With JOLT approach, in the second call you have a json like this: `{ "6100": Api response }`

Comment: Yes need it like this

Comment: How can I do so with jolt?

Comment: @Destiel After that, you can add all your flow content to flow attribute.